# Amibroker: formula personalized per ticker

Tags: trading

is it possible to 'personalize' a formula per each ticker ?
In AFL, i would like to test 'different' buy condition for different ticker.
For example:

Ticker AAPL, Rule A

Ticker MSFT, Rule B

Then, run AFL test each 5 minutes.

Concrete example:

> ticker='AAPL';
>
> Buy = Cross( MACD(), Signal() );
>
> Alertif(..."MAIL", "Buy Apple beacuase Macd Cross");
>
> ticker='MSFT' Buy = Close>EMA(Close,100);
>
> Alertif(..."MAIL", "Buy Apple beacuase Macd Cross");

Etc.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( Name()=="AAPL" )
{
Buy = Cross( MACD(), Signal() );
Alertif(..."MAIL", "Buy Apple beacuase Macd Cross");
}

if ( Name()=="MSFT" )
{
Buy = Close>EMA(Close,100);
Alertif(..."MAIL", "Buy Apple beacuase Macd Cross");
}
```